# Excluding some patterned code in read_chunk knitr function in R

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using `read_chunk` function to read `R` code from external file. Sometimes I add comments for myself but I want to exclude those comments in my final document. I wonder how can the following pattern

```
###################################################
### code chunk number 1:
###################################################
```

can be excluded in `read_chunk` function.

```
###################################################
### code chunk number 1:
###################################################
## ---- Code1 ----
Some Code


###################################################
### code chunk number 2:
###################################################
## ---- Code2 ----
Some Code

###################################################
### code chunk number 3:
###################################################
## ---- Code3 ----
Some Code

###################################################
### The End
###################################################
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can filter out the lines you don't want,

```
code <- "
###################################################
### code chunk number 1:
###################################################
## ---- Code1 ----
ls()


###################################################
### code chunk number 2:
###################################################
## ---- Code2 ----
ls()

###################################################
### code chunk number 3:
###################################################
## ---- Code3 ----
ls()

###################################################
### The End
###################################################
"

codelines <- readLines(textConnection(code))
# if the code is in file 'mycode.txt'
# codelines <- readLines('mycode.txt')
codelines <- codelines[!codelines == ""] # empty lines
keep <- !grepl("###", x=codelines) # comment lines
read_chunk(lines=paste(codelines[keep]))
knitr:::knit_code$get()  
knitr:::knit_code$restore()
```

Comment: Thanks @baptiste for your answer. Can you explain how to use this code for external file. Thanks

Comment: Would highly appreciate if you provide an example code. Thanks